# Joomla / Library / Composer

Tags: php, joomla, composer-php, php-7, joomla-extensions

A question concerning Joomla, Libraries and Composer.

I've developed a library locally using namespaces and composer autoload. My plugin then uses that library and everything works locally as I executed `composer install` inside the library.

Now my question is: How can I execute that `composer install` inside the library when installing the extension on a Joomla! site? (And at the same time: how to `composer update` on library update?)

Thanks for your help :)

[Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/.../joomla/libraries/vendorname/libraryname/vendor/autoload.php']

Answer (score 0):

As per Joomla docs; [Using Composer with Joomla](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Using_Composer_with_Joomla), they do not yet support for additional libraries.

> **Can you install any extra libraries via Composer?**
>
> Not at the moment in Joomla! 3.4. In the longer term it is the CMS's aim that you
>   can download extra packages. To emphasize this, we will not yet be
>   releasing the composer.json file within the main Joomla! download.

What I can suggest you keep that package in a folder and require that autoloader file where you need it.